# Passing parameters from form 1 to form 2

Tags: c#

I have an apllication with two forms and I would like to pass a parameter (foo) from form 1 to form 2, like below:

FORM 1

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Form2 MyForm = new Form2();
    bool foo = false;
    MyForm.Show();
}
```

FORM 2

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (foo == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("foo was false");
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

I get an error saying foo doesn't exist in the current parameter.

Comment: `foo` is a local variable within `Form1` class constructor, so there is no way to use it within `Form2` constructor.

Comment: What's with all the mark downs?  I am new to coding and I don't understand everything yet.  I thought I clearly decribed my question and showed my code.  What was the problem?

Comment: @eltel2910 To quote the downvote tooltip: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear, or not useful."  This information is very readily accessible through research, which you appear not to have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's stopping you from making it a parameter in the constructor?

```
public Form2(bool foo)
{

}
```

Then when instantiating the form:

```
bool foo = false;
Form2 MyForm = new Form2(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make form2s constructor accept an argument, like:

```
bool val;

public Form2(bool arg){
  this.val = arg;
}
```